# What Hibernate Query should I put to retrieve latest record in MS SQL?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Let's say I have an `Entity` class called `Students`

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "dbo.students")
public class Students implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String studentId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String studentName;

    @Column(name = "course")
    private String studentCourse;

    @Column(name = "date_admitted")
    private String dateAdmitted;

}
```

And a `MS SQL` Table called `students`

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

id     name          course             date_admitted
1      Pankesh        EEE            2020-10-21 07:52:30.977
2      Pankesh        IT             2020-11-03 11:53:20.976
3      Pankesh        CE             2020-09-11 08:30:29.975

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What I want to retrieve is the latest record

```
2      Pankesh        IT            2020-11-03 11:53:20.976
```

My `Hibernate` Query

```
session.createQuery("FROM Students WHERE name='"+studentName+"' ORDER BY date_admitted DESC")
```

What `Hibernate` Query should I put for this case?

Note: I'm using `AnnotationMapping` method to map to `MS SQL`

Comment: Shouldn't the latest record have ID=2 (I think you've mixed up your sample data there)?

Comment: Oops my bad. Typo error

Comment: `dateAdmitted` shouldn't be a `String` either. Consider `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`

Comment: It will give me a `Could not deserialize` error. I have tested this before in Java

Comment: When I put it as `String`, I'm able to get the `Hibernate` log

Comment: Double check your source data. Sounds like some of it might not be valid! If you don't get this right now you're headed for a world of pain later.

Comment: this is my `Hibernate` Query: `"FROM Students WHERE name='"+studentName+"' ORDER BY date_admitted DESC"`

Comment: Can anybody answer my question on how to improve my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `entityManager.createQuery("FROM Students WHERE studentName = :name ORDER BY dateAdmitted DESC" ).setParameter("name", studentName).setMaxResults(1).getResultList();`

Comment: But mine is `session.createQuery(FROM Students WHERE name='"+studentName+"' ORDER BY date_admitted DESC)`

Comment: I'm trying to help you here to avoid SQL injection. Never concatenate values to a query. Always use a parameter which does proper escaping for you.

Comment: Why does this potentially lead to SQL injection/breach of data?

Comment: Never heard of bobby tables? https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: nah I've never heard of SQL injection satire

Comment: You also wrongly used the column names instead of the attribute names in the query. Since you are writing JPQL/HQL you need to use the entity model and thus also the entity attribute names rather than column names e.g. `studentName` instead of `name`